# EDSDK callbacks not working

Tags: c++, callback, edsdk

I have a working command line application, using EDSDK v2.13.

However, when I register callbacks, there is a burst of property events then nothing.

I have remedied this a loop like this:

```
while(!_kbhit())
{
  EdsOpenSession(camera);
  Sleep(10);
  EdsCloseSession(camera);
}
```

This seems horribly kludgy. Is the SDK broken, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the EDSDK on Windows, you have to have a Windows message loop in your main thread, otherwise callbacks won't happen. (This is because the EDSDK uses the obsolete COM STA threading model instead of real threads.)

Answer (score 0):

Canons EDSDK is stuck in the 90s, terrible to use. And after a few days of playing with it, it seems much less sophisticated than Nikons.

These companies should implement an http based API on all their cameras like Sony is doing.