# How do I pump window messages in a nodejs addon?

Tags: c++, node.js, winapi, v8, libuv

In a Windows nodejs addon, I've created a window for the purpose of receiving messages.

```
Handle<Value> MakeMessageWindow(const Arguments &args) { // exposed to JS
    ...
    CreateWindow(L"ClassName", NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, 0, 0);
    ...
}
```

I have a wndproc function.

```
Local<Function> wndProc;
LRESULT APIENTRY WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    // pack up the arguments into Local<Value> argv
    wndProc->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 3, argv);
}
```

Now I need to pump messages.  Normally, you'd do something like

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) 
{
     TranslateMessage(&msg);
     DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

...but that won't work since it would just block the v8 event loop.

How do I pump Windows messages in a manner that won't block v8 and allows me to invoke a JS function when my window receives messages?

I presume libuv will play a role, but I'm unsure exactly how to safely invoke a JS function from C running on a separate thread, especially since [`uv_async_send` is not guaranteed to invoke a callback every time you call it](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/threads.html#inter-thread-communication), and I need to ensure that my JS callback is called every time a window message is received.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My mistake was trying to create the window on the V8 thread.  Instead, `uv_thread_create` should be used to call a function that creates the window *on a new thread* and then proceeds to do its own message pump loop.

The wndproc function then needs to save received messages into a queue in a thread-safe manner and then use `uv_async_send` to notify the V8 thread that messages have arrived.

A function on the V8 thread (which was passed to `uv_async_init`) is then invoked after messages are enqueued.  The function (thread-safely) pops each pending message off the queue and invokes the JS callback.

Comment: Great info. Do you, by chance, have a repo or node module that accomplishes this? I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: Did your approach work? I'm having trouble passing callback function into uv_async_send, once the function uv_thread_create is called, I can't get hold of the callback function. Even persistent handles are not working out - I've posted that question in SO too.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159029/how-to-use-persistent-handles-for-callback-functions-in-v8

Comment: Do you have, or know of, a code repo that uses this technique? This is exactly the approach I am taking.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this for Canon's EDSDK, which [requires a message pump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18624865/499151).

libuv's [`uv_idle_t`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/idle.html) is a good candidate for this:

> Despite the name, idle handles will get their callbacks called on every loop iteration, not when the loop is actually “idle”

Example:

```
#include <uv.h>

uv_idle_t* idle = new uv_idle_t();
uv_idle_init(uv_default_loop(), idle);
uv_idle_start(idle, idle_winmsg);

void idle_winmsg (uv_idle_t* idle) {
    MSG msg;
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the actual reason for this.

The Node.js event loop will get stuck on polling for I/O, and given that there is no pending outstanding I/O operation, the event loop will go to sleep.

`idle` and `prepare` are run prior to the I/O polling that the Node.js event loop does but without any work scheduled you may see, at best, 1 or 2 callbacks.

There is no solution to this problem because there is no Win32 message API that can be used to signal an I/O completion port. You have to run the Win32 message loop in a separate thread.